# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript

Quando eu coloco o `[0]` no `let h` acaba dando esse erro

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')
```

Se eu tirar o `[0]`, o código não funciona.

```html
<h1>Titulo</h1>
<input onclick="mudarTexto()" type="submit" value="Mudar">

<script>

   function mudarTexto() {
     let h = document.getElementsByClassName("h1")[0];
     h.innerHTML = "Novo Titulo";

}

</script>
```

Comment: A função `MudarTexto()` não está declarada. (Javascript é uma linguagem de programação case sensitive). Além disso não há nenhum elemento com a className `h1`. Talvez o que queria é pegar um elemento por tag. Segue a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 2):

O método que você está usando é o [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Ele procura uma lista de elementos que tenham a [classe](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) desejada. O problema é seu código HTML não tem nenhuma tag com a **classe** `h1`. No HTML, `<h1>` abre uma tag do **elemento** chamado `h1`, e não classe.

Uma forma mais correta de fazer o que você deseja fazer, é usar o atributo `id` para identificar uma tag de forma única, junto com o método [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

```html
<h1 id="titulo">Titulo</h1>
<input onclick="mudarTexto()" type="submit" value="Mudar">

<script>
function mudarTexto() {
  let h = document.getElementById("titulo");
  h.innerHTML = "Novo Titulo";
}
</script>
```

Dessa forma você dispensa acessar a lista com `[0]`, pois o método utilizado retorna sempre um item somente.